# Order confirmation emails not being sent to guests

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

For some reason, order confirmation emails are being sent to customers who create an account during checkout but not if they checkout as a guest. I also see the error: `Email error. No email address found for order.` in the `commerce.log` file. Anyone know how to get the order confirmations to go out to guest users too? The emails are getting captured, as they show up in the backend. I'm using the latest versions of Craft and Commerce. Thanks!

Update: Even changing the order in the admin to another status and back still does not trigger an email to the user.

Comment: Can you show the config/setup screen for the email please. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by updating to 1.2.1350

https://craftcommerce.com/changelog#build1350